# How do I use an if statement to change the background image of a grandparent element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement

What I am trying to do is use 3 clickable divs as switches which when clicked change the background of an element (using the attribute data-image-src) which is the grandparent of the div.

Heres my HTML:

```
<header class="header-index locations-header col-lg-12 clearfix " data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="images/2V1C8599.jpg">
    <section class="locations-switcher col-md-12 clearfix">
        <div class="first-switch col-sm-4"><h2>div one</h2></div>
        <div class="second-switch col-sm-4"><h2>div two</h2></div>
        <div class="third-switch col-sm-4"><h2>div three</h2></div>
    </section>
</header>
```

and my jQuery:

```
$(".locations-switcher div").click( function() {
        if($("div", this).attr('class') === "first-switch") {
            $(".locations-header").attr( "data-image-src", "../images/IMG_4519_.jpg)" );
        } else if( $("div", this).attr('class') === "second-switch") {
            $(".locations-header").attr( "data-image-src", "../images/2V1C8599.jpg" );
        } else if ($("div", this).attr('class') === "third-switch") {
            $(".locations-header").attr( "data-image-src", "../images/UBC-Interior.jpg" );
        }
    });
```

Any clue to why its not working. I'm still fairly new to javascript and jQuery. Any help would be really great.

Comment: for starters use `$().hasClass('second-switch')` because there are other classes on the element

Answer (score 1):

```
use:
if($(this).hasClass('first-switch')){
instead of:
 if($("div", this).attr('class') === "first-switch") {
```

1. I think `$('div', this)` will look for CHILD divs, you want to look at the element you already found.
2. because there are other classes on the element, `.attr('class')` will return the whole string, `.hasClass()` will check the whole list
3. you have an extra parentheses in the first source string
4. depending on how `data-image-src` is used you might have to trigger something else to redraw it. I usually manually set `.css('background-image', 'url(' + srcString + ')')`

Comment: also likely have to change `data()` not attribute.... probably bound to a plugin that already read the attribute

Comment: If so: Do that like `$(".locations-header").data( "image-src", "../images/UBC-Interior.jpg" );`

Comment: No dice on using data( ) as well as attr( )...

It is a plugin that is reading the attribute. Would I need to integrate the plugin into this function so it reloads and rereads the new data-image-src itself on click?